# Codeigniter - Static Pages tutorial doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, static, routes

I have the  following files:

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "first";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
```

page.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {       
        $this->load->view('first');
    }

    public function view($page = 'first') {

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404()
        }
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
    }
}
?>
```

impressum.php (in views/pages/impressum.php)

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Now when I load http://xxxx.de/page/impressum it shows me just a blank page. When I load www.xxxx.de it shows me the "first" page / default page.
It doesn't even load the "first" page when I try to load: www.xxx.de/page/

Just don't know where I have the error/mistake.

My folder structure is:
http://d.pr/i/vYgw

An help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have /views/pages/first.php view? Try adding die('here'); just in the beggining of the view method and see if it goes there...

Comment: created it, added the line and nothing happend. Like it isn't loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check $page in view method of Page Controller as you are passing any in your route.php file

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
```

www.xxx.de/page/ will pass an empty string or variable to view method you can check it like

```
if(!strlen($page)){
  $page = "first";
}
```

better way to use uri class to get page

```
public function view() {
        $page = $this->uri->segment(2, 'first');

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404()
        }
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
    }
```

if no segment found it will pass first as default

Comment: or just move the slash inside the :any statement - page(/:any)

Comment: Ok, I managed it. a } was missing in the class. Sorry guys. The closing tag for the class wasn't there.
But now I have an another problem. Since the new page is in a second folder (pages/), how do I managed the paths to my assets folder (css, js, etc.) in the view?

Comment: I'm sorry... I thought it worked, but.. nope. And I still don't know why.